# When loading Keras checkpoint the validation loss increases on first evaluation

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm having an issue with model saving and loading (fine-tuning).

After I load the model that was saved at val_loss 0.8, on first epoch it will be evaluated to 0.85 or so, even if the model never climbed more than 0.82 for example on previous training (just went flat).
The ModelCheckpoint then will save it at that point (seems like it starts from inf?) overwriting any previous progress.

I'm saving checkpoints like this:

```
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(
    "count_fingers.h5",
    #filepath="weights.{epoch:02d}-{val_loss:.2f}.h5",
    monitor= "val_loss",
    verbose= 1,
    save_best_only= True,
    #save_weights_only= True,
    save_freq="epoch"
)
```

and loading like this:

```
model = tf.keras.models.load_model("count_fingers.h5")
```

I've tried also `model.load_weights`.

After some search I think it might be related to the optimizer decay? That will have a big learning rate on first epoch? Not sure.

If you can let me know what I'm doing wrong or why this is happening and what's the right approach to continue exactly from where I've left?

Thank you,

Adrian

Comment: 1. Have you frozen the weights? 2. Do you use a sufficiently small learning rate? Please, note that a (relatively) very small learning rate is needed when fine-tuning. The goal is to limit the magnitude of the modifications of the representations of the layers that are being fine-tuned (Source: "Deep Learning with Python" by Francois Chollet).

Comment: I didn't frozen the weights as I want it to continue learning. I did decrease the learning rate, tried a factor of 0.1, 0.01, ...